# Query not working in MC

Tags: marketing-cloud, query

my query is not working, can you help me please?

```
SELECT Id FROM DE_test1 WHERE Id="0032X00002NNlK7QAL"
```

Error: Error saving the Query field.Incorrect syntax near 'X00002NNlK7QAL'.

Answer (score 2):

Can you please try with single quotes, and to be on the safe side, wrap the DE name in square brackets:

```
SELECT Id FROM [DE_test1] WHERE Id = '0032X00002NNlK7QAL'
```

If you're running this is Query Studio, please give it a few tries - Query Studio isn't always reliable ;-)

Comment: @manuel if this answer helped you, please remember to accept it by clicking the checkmark - thanks!